# How to make Apache eCharts NOT clickable?

Tags: echarts

I have a Gauge chart created with Apache eCharts.

But I am only using it for display purposes to show a "website score". Therefore I want to make it non-clickable.

How do I do that?

At the moment the circular axis line is clickable. I want to disable that.

Here is my code:

```JavaScript
const option = {
  series: [
    {
      data: gaugeData,
      type: 'gauge',
      startAngle: 90,
      endAngle: -270,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      progress: {
        show: true,
        width: 10,
        roundCap: true,
      },
      pointer: {
        show: false,
      },
      axisLine: {
        lineStyle: {
          width: 10,
        },
      },
      axisTick: {
        show: false,
      },
      splitLine: {
        show: false,
      },
      axisLabel: {
        show: false,
      },
      title: {
        show: false,
      },
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#ee6666',
      },
      detail: {
        formatter: '{value}',
        color: 'auto',
        offsetCenter: [0, '-0%'],
        valueAnimation: true,
        fontSize: 34,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't permanenetly set the cursor in Echarts. But, if you don't want the mouse pointer to change when hovering the line, there are a few solutions :

- Your chart is associated to a `<div>`. Let's say its id is `main`, you can force the cursor to 'default' inside that div (using CSS):

```css
#main *{
    cursor: default !important;
}
```

- Otherwise, you can use this workaround only using Echarts :

```js
// Same cursor everywhere on your chart
myChart.on('mousemove', function (params) {
    myChart.getZr().setCursorStyle('default');
});
```

Basically, it will set the cursor back to 'default' (or to whatever you want) everytime the mouse moves. This trick is less performant than the first option but it doesn't seem to affect performance that much, as long as your dataset isn't too big (but in the case of a gauge, it should be ok).

- In either case you'll also want this :

```js
//Remove the emphasis on the line when hovering
series: [
{
  ... // your other options
  emphasis : {
    disabled : true
  }
}]
```

An event will still be emitted each time the user hovers the line, but he won't see it (so it will not look clickable).

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
series: [
{
  ...
  silent: true,
  ...
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
axisLabel: {
    show: false,
    clickable: false
},
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work. The ring is still clickable. The mouse pointer still changes into a clickable pointer.

Comment: mouse pointer is triggered by which element? axisLabel or others ?

Comment: The "progress" bar. I have tried adding `clickable: false` to that but it doesnt work either. `progress: { show: true, width: 10, roundCap: true, clickable: false },`